# Is it possible to write a shell similar to bash using only pure Java?

Tags: java, bash, shell

I know C (or why not C++) is the natural choice for this, but for personal reasons I want to try it in Java.

What I want to implement:

- `|`
- `>`
- `>>`
- some built-ins like `echo` and `if`

I was thinking of using ProcessBuilder, PipedInputStream, PipedOutputStream and the likes to achieve my goal.

Do you think this is possible without relying on JNI?

Should I use a tool like antlr to help me with the grammar, or do you think it's overkill for what I need?

Any other suggestions, materials?

Comment: As long as you're not supporting Windows it shouldn't be too much more difficult in Java than in any other language.

Comment: possible duplicate of [POSIX shell like implementation in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399075/posix-shell-like-implementation-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be an exercise of duplication, but if you want to do it just for the sake of doing it, you should start with [jline](http://jline.sourceforge.net/) for the console handling part if you want to duplicate a console. [jline](http://jline.sourceforge.net/) handles all the *native* stuff so there is no JNI that you have to deal with. [jline](http://jline.sourceforge.net/) works with OSX, Linux and Windows equally.

ANTLR will not be of any benefit for doing something as simple as this, but a command line parser like [JSAP](http://www.martiansoftware.com/jsap/) will be of use.

jline and JSAP would give you everything you need to build a functional shell and command line parsing for "*commands*" that the shell supports.

Answer (score 1):

The only real challenge for this is the actual parsing of the input, especially if you want to simulate say bash for example, in which cause I would definitely use Antlr to build the grammar and the associated code for that.  I do not think that using Antlr would be overkill as it would help provide correct parsing and make your life implementing the actual shell functions easier because it would remove a significant portion of code that you would have to write.  Some areas may need JNI, but I do not think it would be a very significant portion of code besides a few special cases at most.

I would look at other shell implementations also I know there are a few college courses that cover Operating Systems that have assignments similar to this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.  Indeed it has been done, in JNode.  JNode includes a shell called "bjorne" that is more or less complete, and more or less POSIX compatible.

The catch is that in its current form "bjorne" runs commands that execute on/under the JNode operating system, rather than on a Linux or Windows platform.  So the "interface" used to launch commands does not rely on fork/exec or `Process`, like an implementation on a classic JVM would need to.  But that was the whole point of the exercise ...

---

If you are implementing this yourself, Antlr won't help much because the basic shell grammar is context sensitive.  Besides, the "hard bits" in implementing POSIX are in getting quoting and expansion right, and in handling subshells, redirection and the like.

Answer (score 1):

There is http://www.beanshell.org/ which has been around for years and is used in many IDE's debuggers for evaluated expressions.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, especially with simple requirements like `| > >>` and `for`. However, you won't be able to implement some functionalities like exec without native code. You might use [JShell](http://www.geophile.com/jshell/) as a starting point. There is some work to do to make it compile with current JDK and libraries though.